# Namecheap\Mailgun - receiving email

Tags: laravel, dns, mailgun, namecheap

I am wondering how to setup namcheap and maligun to receive emails. Currently I am able to send emails with my laravel application through maligun, but I am not sure how to setup maligun to receives replies?
I have seen the options of setting up routes to receive emails to some wanted enpoint, but currently I am not receiving anything on maligun, so I have nothing to forward. I am getting the message:

> This is the mail system at host eforward3e.registrar-servers.com.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not be
>   delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can delete your
>   own text from the attached returned message.
>
> ```
>                The mail system
> ```
>
> : unknown user:
>   "support@my-domain.com"
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; support@my-domain.com
>   Original-Recipient: rfc822;support@my-domain.com Action: failed
>   Status: 5.1.1 Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user:
>   "support@my-domain.com"

How should I set this up?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Mailgun have this in their documentation: [mailgun](http://mailgun-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart-receiving.html)

Comment: Well, I am not sure how to set it up, my maligun domain name is mail.my-domain.com and I am sending emails from my application as support@my-domain.com, do I need to change this, and if so, where should I change it, in the application or maligun?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you register your domain at [mailgun](https://mailgun.com), if not then do it [here](https://mailgun.com/signup). Once your domain register follow below steps:

1) Get **domain** and **API Key** from *Mailgun > Doamins > Domain Information* page
2) Setup `config/services.php`:

```
'mailgun' => array(
    'domain' => 'YOURDOMAINNAME',//Place your register domain name here...
    'secret' => 'API Key',//Place your API Key here...
),
```

3) Setup `.env`:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=YOURPASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

4) Check with sending mail from laravel application.

That's it...

Comment: I am able to send email, and I have setup everything like you have described, butwhat I want to do now, is to setup receiving emails, from for example my gmail account to my support@my-domain.com address

Comment: @Leff: Check [this](http://mailgun-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart-receiving.html#supported-actions-for-routes) out. It might help you

Comment: sorry, my question was probably misleading since I myself don't know where the problem is, but I posted the error message in the question, which points out that I need to setup the DNS server

Comment: uh, without DNS, how it work? Hope now you got the problem and it's solution correct?